# How to handle NA in the input pandas dataframe. current working code enclosed

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Dataframe to start with below. Currently the below working code does not handle 'NA' value in input dataframe. I want to update the code such that it is able to handle 'NA' values in input dataframe.

Each input column 'Delivery Time zone overlap', creates three output columns 1.'Delivery Team colocation'  2.'Delivery Team overlap', 3.'Delivery opposite timezone'

If 'Delivery Time zone overlap' column has 'NA' value, push 'NA' value into three output columns 1.'Delivery Team colocation'  2.'Delivery Team overlap', 3.'Delivery opposite timezone'

Same treatment for the other two input columns.

```
import pandas as pd

# create input dataframe
delivery_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Delivery Time zone overlap': [3, 3, 11.5, 3, 0, 9.5],
    'Developer & Product Time zone overlap': [3, 3, 11.5, 3, 0, 9.5],
    'Developer & Agile champion Time zone overlap': [3, 3, 11.5, 3, 0, 9.5]
})

# create output dataframe
output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
    'Delivery Team colocation', 'Delivery Team overlap', 'Delivery opposite timezone',
    'Developer & Product colocation', 'Developer & Product overlap', 'Developer & Product opposite timezone',
    'Developer & Agile champion colocation', 'Developer & Agile champion overlap', 'Developer & Agile champion opposite timezone'
])

# update the output dataframe based on the input dataframe values
for index, row in delivery_df.iterrows():
    delivery_overlap = row['Delivery Time zone overlap']
    dev_prod_overlap = row['Developer & Product Time zone overlap']
    dev_agile_overlap = row['Developer & Agile champion Time zone overlap']

    if delivery_overlap == 0:
        output_df = output_df.append({
            'Delivery Team colocation': 'Delivery Team is colocated',
            'Developer & Product colocation': 'Developer & Product are colocated',
            'Developer & Agile champion colocation': 'Developer & Agile champion are colocated'
        }, ignore_index=True)

    elif 1 <= delivery_overlap <= 5.5:
        output_df = output_df.append({
            'Delivery Team overlap': 'Delivery Team has overlap',
            'Developer & Product overlap': 'Developer & Product has overlap',
            'Developer & Agile champion overlap': 'Developer & Agile champion has overlap'
        }, ignore_index=True)

    else:
        output_df = output_df.append({
            'Delivery opposite timezone': 'Delivery Team in opposite timezone',
            'Developer & Product opposite timezone': 'Developer & Product in opposite timezone',
            'Developer & Agile champion opposite timezone': 'Developer & Agile champion in opposite timezone'
        }, ignore_index=True)

# print the output dataframe
print(output_df)
```

Comment: Please don't use the `js snippet` for `python` code.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add add an if statement to check if each input value is `NaN` using `pd.isna()`.

```
import pandas as pd

delivery_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Delivery Time zone overlap': [3, 3, 11.5, 3, 0, 9.5, pd.NA],
    'Developer & Product Time zone overlap': [3, 3, 11.5, 3, 0, 9.5, pd.NA],
    'Developer & Agile champion Time zone overlap': [3, 3, 11.5, 3, 0, 9.5, pd.NA]
})

output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
    'Delivery Team colocation', 'Delivery Team overlap', 'Delivery opposite timezone',
    'Developer & Product colocation', 'Developer & Product overlap', 'Developer & Product opposite timezone',
    'Developer & Agile champion colocation', 'Developer & Agile champion overlap', 'Developer & Agile champion opposite timezone'
])

for index, row in delivery_df.iterrows():
    delivery_overlap = row['Delivery Time zone overlap']
    dev_prod_overlap = row['Developer & Product Time zone overlap']
    dev_agile_overlap = row['Developer & Agile champion Time zone overlap']

    if pd.isna(delivery_overlap): 
        output_df = output_df.append({
            'Delivery Team colocation': pd.NA, 
            'Delivery Team overlap': pd.NA,
            'Delivery opposite timezone': pd.NA,
        }, ignore_index=True)
    elif delivery_overlap == 0:
        output_df = output_df.append({
            'Delivery Team colocation': 'Delivery Team is colocated',
            'Developer & Product colocation': 'Developer & Product are colocated',
            'Developer & Agile champion colocation': 'Developer & Agile champion are colocated'
        }, ignore_index=True)

    elif 1 <= delivery_overlap <= 5.5:
        output_df = output_df.append({
            'Delivery Team overlap': 'Delivery Team has overlap',
            'Developer & Product overlap': 'Developer & Product has overlap',
            'Developer & Agile champion overlap': 'Developer & Agile champion has overlap'
        }, ignore_index=True)

    else:
        output_df = output_df.append({
            'Delivery opposite timezone': 'Delivery Team in opposite timezone',
            'Developer & Product opposite timezone': 'Developer & Product in opposite timezone',
            'Developer & Agile champion opposite timezone': 'Developer & Agile champion in opposite timezone'
        }, ignore_index=True)

print(output_df)
```

which gives

```
     Delivery Team colocation      Delivery Team overlap  \
0                         NaN  Delivery Team has overlap   
1                         NaN  Delivery Team has overlap   
2                         NaN                        NaN   
3                         NaN  Delivery Team has overlap   
4  Delivery Team is colocated                        NaN   
5                         NaN                        NaN   
6                         NaN                        NaN   

           Delivery opposite timezone     Developer & Product colocation  \
0                                 NaN                                NaN   
1                                 NaN                                NaN   
2  Delivery Team in opposite timezone                                NaN   
3                                 NaN                                NaN   
4                                 NaN  Developer & Product are colocated   
5  Delivery Team in opposite timezone                                NaN   
6                                 NaN                                NaN   

       Developer & Product overlap     Developer & Product opposite timezone  \
0  Developer & Product has overlap                                       NaN   
1  Developer & Product has overlap                                       NaN   
2                              NaN  Developer & Product in opposite timezone   
3  Developer & Product has overlap                                       NaN   
4                              NaN                                       NaN   
5                              NaN  Developer & Product in opposite timezone   
6                              NaN                                       NaN   

      Developer & Agile champion colocation  \
0                                       NaN   
1                                       NaN   
2                                       NaN   
3                                       NaN   
4  Developer & Agile champion are colocated   
5                                       NaN   
6                                       NaN   

       Developer & Agile champion overlap  \
0  Developer & Agile champion has overlap   
1  Developer & Agile champion has overlap   
2                                     NaN   
3  Developer & Agile champion has overlap   
4                                     NaN   
5                                     NaN   
6                                     NaN   

      Developer & Agile champion opposite timezone  
0                                              NaN  
1                                              NaN  
2  Developer & Agile champion in opposite timezone  
3                                              NaN  
4                                              NaN  
5  Developer & Agile champion in opposite timezone  
6                                              NaN
```